# C++ Overloaded Function and Subclasses

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, overloading

Suppose I have:

```
struct Vehicle {...}
struct Car : public Vehicle {...}

string A(Vehicle *v) { return "vehicle"; }
string A(Car *c) { return "car"; }
```

And I do this:

```
Vehicle *v = new Car();
cout << A(v);
```

Why does the compiler print out "vehicle"? After all, v points to a Car object.

Comment: Did you try running it to see what happens?

Comment: Did you try compiling it? There should be a warning at least...

Comment: Definitely -1 on this question- could have been instantaneously resolved with a minute's effort with a compiler.

Comment: @Doug @Flinsch @DeadMG, I'm not interested in what a compiler does. I'm interested in learning what the C++ spec says and why. e.g. it could be undefined.

Comment: Except no implementation is non-conformant on anything like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overloaded function `A(Vehicle*)` is a better match for argument of type `Vehicle*`. So the `cout` will print:

```
vehicle
```

**Explanation:**

The overloaded function resolution is done based on the **static** type of argument. And the *static* type of the argument `v` is `Vehicle*`. Therefore, the function `A(Vehicle*)` will be called.

Answer (score 1):

```
"vehicle"
```

gets printed out

This happens because the static type of v is a Vehicle. So the A defined for Vehicle gets used by the compiler.

The compiler uses dynamic type information when calling a member function to do virtual method calls. The keyword virtual is required. In this case the "this" pointer will be appropriately downcast at the appropriate override level.

However, outside of this special case the compiler won't downcast for you without an explicit dynamic_cast.

Answer (score 1):

This is example of static binding. During compilation it is clear that `string A(Vehicle *v)` function will be called. Of course "vehicle" should be in output.